# FTP access inside docker for a PHP envrionnement

Tags: php, docker, ftp

I have a web server with multiple PHP website. I push all my updates through FTP.

I intend to move to a more containerized environnement without changing to much of my current basic workflow.

I would like to deploy each of my website in a Docker container. The database for all the website would be in another container. 
I will have a Docker as a reverse proxy.

To update my website, i have two ideas :

- Set up an FTP access in the container so i can update it directly
- Set up a shared directories with the host through volume, so i can set up FTP access from the host.

What do you think of it ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Updating the content of a container at run time is against the idea of such containers, though certainly that would be possible. Instead you should recreate the container whenever the code changes. A container should always be built from a fixed version of the code you want to execute inside that container. Think of it as a packaging utility if you like. Because of that I personally would even advise against shared directories for that but copy the code into the container instead.

Comment: YOu could use `mount --bind`  to access the containers as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the code inside a running container, or at all, is against docker [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/), as containers are designed to be ephemeral.

A better idea would be to rebuild the image every time you update the code, allowing the containers to [stay ephemeral](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/), and making it easier to scale. You could implement this through CI/CD, but that is out of the scope of this question.

If you *really* want to continue with the idea of ftp still, it's a good idea to have one container with an ftp service in it, and another one with the web server in, as containers should [have only one concern](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/).

If your FTP server image is `my/ftp-image` and your web server is `my/web-server-image`, then you can start your containers like this:

```
docker run -itd --name my-web-server -p 80:80 -v files_volume_name_here:/path/to/files/in/container my/web-server-image
docker run -itd --name my-ftp-server [ports for ftp server here] -v files_volume_name_here:/path/to/files/in/container my/ftp-image
```